# Maven TestNG transactional test, maven runs test but results is test run: 0

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, testng, maven-3

I'm writing some test for simple hibernate app with spring using TestNG and mvn. My problem : when running

```
mvn clean install
```

Maven returns:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.me.service.test.BorowerTest
Configuring TestNG with:
org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configurator@77556fd
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.375 sec

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

My test class:

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.Rollback;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.testng.Assert;

import com.me.daoImpl.Borrower.BorrowerDAOImpl;
import com.altkom.model.Borrower.Borrower;

@Transactional
public class BorowerTest {

@Autowired
private BorrowerDAOImpl borrowerDAOImpl;
private Borrower borrowerOne;
private Borrower borrowerTwo;

@Before
public void setUpData() {
    borrowerOne = new Borrower.BorrowerBuilder().firstName("Dave").lastName("Lombardo").adress("New York")
            .phoneNumber("666666666").build();
    borrowerTwo = new Borrower.BorrowerBuilder().firstName("Tom").lastName("Araya").adress("Los Angeles")
            .phoneNumber("445533123").build();
}

@Test
@Rollback(false)
public void persistBorrowerTest() {
    boolean test = borrowerDAOImpl.persist(borrowerOne) && borrowerDAOImpl.persist(borrowerTwo);
    Assert.assertTrue(test);
}

}
```

I can't find the proper solution. In pom I've only configured compiler plugin for java 1.8.

Comment: `import org.testng.annotations.Test;` for testNg tests. You are importing `import org.junit.Test;`

Comment: could you please share your pom.xml here as well